# Formatar texto no Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Bem estou precisando imprimir um boleto bancário com seguinte. Nosso numero dever ficar assim
15/200020-3.
Esse mesmo numero está salvo no BD assim: 152000203.
Como faço para colocar a barra na 3ª casa, e o tracinho 10ª?

Answer (score 2):

O que fiz para resolver meu problema foi o seguinte:

Usei uma fórmula para exibir o campo no relatório no formato desejado. 
Selecione Formula Field.Informe o nome para a fórmula e clique em OK

```
{boleto1.nossonumero} [1 to 2]+"/"+{boleto1.nossonumero} [3 to 8]+"-"+{boleto1.nossonumero} [9 to 9]
```

Links com mais formas de formatação no Crystal Report:

[Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/crys_rpt.htm) e [FabioMed](http://www.fabiobmed.com.br/funcao-totext-crystal-reports/)